# Applying adapter concept in google maps Marker android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, adapter

I populate my google maps with number of `Markers` based on my server data.

MY server data contains `ProfilePic , Name , Designation , & lat long etc...`

When I click on my `Marker` I open `BottomSheet` that display the details like `ProfilePic , Name , Designation` . **just like google map does**

I don't know how do I get ProfilePic and other data on click of my marker .

I am very familiar to `Recyclerview adapter` concept ,

How do I apply this concept to my marker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set custom adapters of infowindow for marker in google map.. check this example--http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html

Comment: Sorry I am not using infoWindow . Any other solution

Comment: Using infoWindow you can show on data...what your using now?

Comment: You can append position of marker and while click on it you get title and take values from list :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1-> You can use HashMap for mapping of markers and your server data list.

Solution 2-> You can append the id or position to marker title with token(comma, semicolon...) and then onClick marker you can break them for further mapping to your server data list. 
In this case you also need to override customInfoWindow.

Example to follow:-
http://devlearning.blogspot.in/2014/05/android-custom-info-window-with.html

Hope this may helpful to you

Thanks,

Bhuvnesh

Comment: Any example to go through ?

Comment: Follow this link: http://devlearning.blogspot.in/2014/05/android-custom-info-window-with.html